# How do I get the user to press 1 out of 10 buttons in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

my question is how do I get the user to press 1 out of 10 buttons in html I know radio buttons are "ideal", but for my purpose...it's not.

Comment: What do you mean by "get the user to press ... buttons"?

Comment: Please clarify your question and add your code. You can't "force" a visitor of your website to do anything. So you'll never get a user to press a button if they don't want to. See how unclear your question is?

Comment: Is the problem that radio buttons look wrong? CSS can do that; if you have labels properly associated with the radio buttons, you can hide them and the labels can be interacted with.

Answer (score 1):

You could disable all buttons that weren't clicked by adding a click listener to disable all the others.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container")
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".single-select")

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    buttons.forEach(button1 => button1.disabled = true)
    e.target.disabled = false
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="single-select">Click just one</button>
  <button class="single-select">Click just one</button>
  <button class="single-select">Click just one</button>
  <button class="single-select">Click just one</button>
  <button class="single-select">Click just one</button>
</div>
```